# Bluetooth versus WiFi

Tags: rf, bluetooth, wifi

Why there are two communication standards, Bluetooth and WIFI? Why not used just one, when they both works in the same 2.4 GHz band?

Comment: There much more communication standards than just two. They are designed for different applications and requirements, that's why.

Comment: Is bluetooth some type of wireless ad-hoc network?

Comment: Reading about it on a dedicated resource will provide you much more information than the comments here.

Comment: I think this was a question that resulted in a helpful answer.

Comment: Why use a ship/train/plane when cars and bikes and shoes exist? They all work on this planet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bluetooth and wifi serve very different purposes.

Bluetooth is designed for connecting peripherals to computers at short range (<10M) and moderate data rates. It aims to minimize power consumption. Think of it as wireless USB.

Wifi is designed for connecting computers to networks at moderate range (5-50M) and high data rates. It aims to maximize range and data throughput, while not being unduly power intensive for computers. Think of it as wireless ethernet.

Comment: +1 for the good analogies, which still work, even when expanded. Is it worth adding that their are multiple standards within WiFi and Bluetooth? As technology and requirements have evolved, there are newer versions of those standards intended to increase data rate, or power. Like USB 1, 1.2, 2 and 3, or Wifi a/b/c/n/...